# Why is this class not considered a supertype as a parameter?

Tags: java, overriding, supertype

Given the following example, why am I able to override the return type `List<? extends IConfigUser>` as `List<ConfigUser>` in `getUserList()` but cannot do the same for the parameter of `setUserList()`?

Isn't `ConfigUser` considered a supertype of `IConfigUser` in this case?

```
public class Test {
   public interface IConfigUser {
   }

   public interface IConfig {
      public List<? extends IConfigUser> getUserList();
      public void setUserList(List<? extends IConfigUser> list);
   }


   public class ConfigUser implements IConfigUser {
   }

   // The type Test.Config must implement the inherited abstract method
   // Test.IConfig.setUserList(List<? extends Test.IConfigUser>)
   public class Config implements IConfig {
      @Override
      public List<ConfigUser> getUserList() {
         return null;
      }

      // The method setUserList(List<ConfigUser> list) of type Test.Config
      // must override or implement a supertype method
      @Override
      public void setUserList(List<ConfigUser> list)
      {
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Imagine if that *did* compile, and then someone passed in a List<NotAConfigUser>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return ("specialize") the return type of `getUserList()` due to covariance, i.e. if you call that method on a `IConfig` reference  all you know is that you'll get a `List<? extends IConfigUser>` and a `List<ConfigUser>`  *is a* `List<? extends IConfigUser>` so the requirements are satisfied.

If you call that on a `Config` reference the information is more concrete but the basic requirements are still met.

With `setUserList(...)` the situation is different: it allows you to pass *any* "subclass" of `List<? extends IConfigUser>` which *can be* a `List<ConfigUser>` but it also can be something else, e.g. a `List<SomeConfigUser>`.

Btw, since you don't know the concrete generic parameter of `list` in `setUserList(List<ConfigUser> list)` the compiler will also only allow you to read from that list, never add to it - for the same reason as above: you don't know what you get and whether adding a `ConfigUser` is allowed because the list could only allow `SomeConfigUser` instances to be added.

Comment: Thank you for thoroughly explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your goal by adding a generic type parameter to `IConfig`:

```
public class Test {
   public interface IConfigUser {
   }

   public interface IConfig<T extends IConfigUser> {
      public List<T> getUserList();
      public void setUserList(List<T> list);
   }


   public class ConfigUser implements IConfigUser {
   }

   public class Config implements IConfig<ConfigUser> {
      @Override
      public List<ConfigUser> getUserList() {
         return null;
      }

      @Override
      public void setUserList(List<ConfigUser> list)
      {
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *return* a more specific type in an override, but you can't require that you *accept* a more specific type. Get rid of the generics, and you can override a method returning `Object` with a method returning `String`, but you can't override a method accepting an `Object` parameter with a method accepting a `String` parameter.

All of this is so that callers are compatible. Consider:

```
IConfig config = new Config();    
List<SomeOtherConfigUser> list = new ArrayList<SomeOtherConfigUser>();
list.add(new SomeOtherConfigUser());
config.setUserList(list);
```

Oops - your `Config.setUserList` is expecting every element to be a `ConfigUser`, not a `SomeOtherConfigUser`.